# Return video to start when it's ended

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-video

I have simple simple tag in my html:

```
<video id="vid" controls="controls">
  <source src="mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Tried this:

```
$(document).ready(function (){
 myVid=document.getElementById("vid");
   myVid.onloadedmetadata=function(){
   if (myVid.ended == true) {
     myVid.currentTime = 0;
   }
 }
});
```

Any ideas how can I return video to start when it's ended?

Comment: @3rror404 seen it, it's not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing is basically checking if the video has ended after loading the metadata e.g. loading the metadata of the video in the browsers. You need to use an event once the video has ended.

Use the onended event instead

```
  myVid.onended = function(e) { myVid.currentTime = 0; myVid.play(); }
```

try this...

```
 $(document).ready(function (){
   myVid=document.getElementById("vid");
   myVid.onended = function(e) { myVid.currentTime = 0; myVid.play(); }
 });
```

Here is a jsfiddle if you don't belive me.
http://jsfiddle.net/004s1fun/

Comment: unfortunately does not work

Comment: nope, doesn't work, you can chack your part of code here http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_av_prop_ended

Comment: if you insert 'myVid.onended = function(e) { myVid.currentTime = 0; myVid.play(); }' there it works, just tried it.

Comment: dont forget to click submit.

Comment: Maybe you don't have jquery linked on your page

Comment: oh, something slows me today:)
tnx a lot!